# Not all labels printing

Tags: address-labels

I have a list of 36 contacts. When printing labels using Primary address it only prints the first 14 (first based on contact ID number, not alphabetically). When printing labels using Home address it prints all of them. All contacts have home addresses, all set to primary. Nobody has any contact restrictions. An export from the address table showed no commonalities between those that did or did not print other than the order of their contact ID number. This problem seems to be new/unique to 4.7.23 (Drupal) as far as we know (ie we didn't notice it happening before). The 4.7.25 sandbox does not seem to have this same quirk.

Summary question: What would cause Civi to print labels for only a subset of valid, mailable addresses?

Comment: sounds truly odd if you are certain that all 36 records do have an address set as Primary (ie we have seen cases of dbs where no address was set as primary)

Comment: Absolutely certain in this case. Even went through the trouble of re-saving addresses on a couple missing records in the GUI to be sure. No effect. In the civicrm_address table, all have is_primary=1